# what causes node gyp err?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

lately, I installed mongoose and some modules. in node 4.0.0v
there is no err when i installed mongoose.
but, now I install node 4.2.2v and remove all modules using `rm -rf node-modules` and reinstall using `npm install` with this json file.

```
{
 "name": "MEAN",

  "version": "0.0.3",

  "dependencies": {

    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^0.4.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-session": "^1.12.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.4",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7"
  }
}
```

and then it causes many errors like this.

```
gyp ERR! build error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/afuser/Desktop/wonchan/mean/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil

gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3

gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
```

I find answer to fix this error.
but, what i really want to know is why install mongoose 3.8.3 doesn't make error.
I think mongoose 3.8.3 is pure JS, and mongoose 4.x is native module.
 what i think is right?

Comment: Try `sudo npm install` if that fails, install n (`sudo npm install n -g`) and use it like this: `n node stable` and `n npm stable` then try `sudo npm install` again.